# php artisan key:generate runs successfully but no key is generated PHP 7.4.9

Tags: php, laravel

I just pulled my project from GitHub with an intention of working on it but then when I run  `PHP artisan key: generate` after doing `composer install`, `PHP artisan config: cache` and making sure that I have the .env file in the root directory,  the command runs successfully but no key is generated. A quick search gives me solutions such as making sure I have a `.env` file, I do `PHP artisan config: clear/cache`, I do `composer update --no-scripts` etc. I have done all those but then realized again that it might be an error with PHP 7.4 from this post on GitHub:
https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/32059

Could anyone suggest possible solutions to this problem?

Comment: so the `APP_KEY` does not end up set in the `.env` file after running the command?

Comment: YES, The command runs successfully saying the key has been generated but no key is generated

Comment: don't know what to tell you ... just run `php artisan key:generate --show` and copy that key yourself into `.env` for now